# Scale image-views to different devices

Tags: android, image, imageview, scale

I create a view with an image-view at the top of the view.
The images are in size 1080-800px. If I take a look on my HTC One, it is perfekt. The image width takes the whole-screen. If I take another device , which is bigger or shorter , the images are to small or to big! I put the images to the drawable-xxhdpi folder.
Should I scale them with photoshop to different sizes?

[image]

You can see, the size at the left is perfekt, but how I can handle bigger devices like that one on the right side?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/layout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Crunch"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >




            <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/crunch1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/crunch2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/crunch" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TVTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="verlaufKlick"
    android:text="@string/pause"
    android:visibility="invisible"
      />

</LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and add

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: I think this answer coupled with @wael's answer is the best choice - Wael's answer is good because you won't be pulling very large images into memory to only use a scaled version (which can lead to OOM errors), and TheOsirian's answer covers all bases for making sure the image is displayed to the full widhth of the screen, and not tiled

Comment: I've add this to my both Image-Views, but there isn't any change.

Comment: Maybe you need to set `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

Answer (score 2):

put your image (with the same name) with different resolution in

```
drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi
```

[image]

so that android will choose automatically the image that corresponds to your screen resolution

Comment: Thanks, I've put my 1080*800 size image to xxhdpi? Where should I put the larger ones?

Comment: You should put the larger one in drawable-xhdpi and the largest in drawable-xxhdpi, and you should try and test